# How to get a 50/50 chance in random generator

Tags: java

I am trying to get a 50/50 chance of get either 1 or 2 in a random generator.

For example:

```
Random random = new Random();
int num = random.nextInt(2)+1;
```

This code will output either a 1 or 2.

Let's say I run it in a loop:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    int num = random.nextInt(2)+1 ;
}
```

How can I make the generator make an equal number for 1 and 2 in this case?

So I want this loop to generate 50 times of number 1 and 50 times of number 2.

Comment: As many others have noted, you're confused here I think: if you toss a coin 100 times, your *expectation* is 50 heads. Any number between 0 and 100 is possible, with varying probability. I think you're falling for the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_fallacy

Comment: Actually your expectation shouldn't be 50 heads, but rather between 45 and 55 heads... :D. Its just that 50 heads itself is the most likely (around 8% chance of that happening)

Comment: @AntonRoth, [no](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value).

Answer (score 53):

One way: fill an `ArrayList<Integer>` with fifty 1's and fifty 2's and then call `Collection.shuffle(...)` on it.

Comment: Assuming @Sulaiman actually wants exactly 50 1's and 2's, this is it.  But just gotta point out that the actual randomness is gone (which may have lead to 47 1's and 53 2's or similar).

Comment: @Mercurybullet: I agree 100%. As per usual, the exact solution depends completely on his requirements

Comment: Why so hard to generate a random sequence?

Answer (score 28):

50/50 is quite easy with **Random.nextBoolean()**

```
private final Random random = new Random();

private int next() {
  if (random.nextBoolean()) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Test Run:

```
final ListMultimap<Integer, Integer> histogram = LinkedListMultimap.create(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    nal Integer result = Integer.valueOf(next());
  histogram.put(result, result);
}
for (final Integer key : histogram.keySet()) {
  System.out.println(key + ": " + histogram.get(key).size());
}
```

Result:

```
1: 5056
2: 4944
```

Comment: He wants (from what I understood) 50 1s and 50 2s **exactly**. What you posted will give the same results as what he already has.

Comment: If ternary operator is preferred  `private int next() { return random.nextBoolean() ? 1 : 2; }`

Answer (score 20):

You can't achieve this with `random`. If you need **exactly** 50 1s and 50 2s, you should try something like this:

```
int[] array = new int[100];
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i)
 array[i] = 1;
for (int i = 50; i < 100; ++i)
 array[i] = 2;

shuffle(array); // implement shuffling algorithm or use an already existing one
```

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**
*I understand that if you are looking to accomplish exactly 50-50 results, then my answer was not accurate. You should use a pre-filled collection, since it is impossible to achive that using any kind of randomness. This considered, my answer is still valid for the title of the question, so, this is it:*

Well, you do not need the rnd generator to do this.
Comming from javascript, I would go with a single liner:

```
return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 1: 2;
```

Explanation: **Math.random()** returns a number between 0(inclusive) and 1(exclusive), so, we just examine weather is larger than 0.5 (middle value). In theory there is a 50% change that does.

For a more generic use, you can just replace **1:2** to **true:false**

Answer (score 2):

You can adjust the probability along the way so that the probability of getting a one decreases as you get more ones. This way you don't always have a 50% chance of getting a one, but you can get the result you expected (exactly 50 ones):

```
int onesLeft = 50;

for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
  int totalLeft = 100 - i;
  // we need a probability of onesLeft out of (totalLeft)
  int r = random.nextInt(totalLeft);
  int num;
  if(r < onesLeft) {
    num = 1;
    onesLeft --;
  } else {
    num = 2;
  }
}
```

This has an advantage over shuffling because it generates numbers incrementally so it desn't need memory to store the numbers.

Comment: But the distribution won't be uniform, you're most likely to go the end filled with identical numbers.

Comment: @lechlukasz, I thought about that, but I can't seem to prove or disprove that. Can you?

Comment: @lechlukasz, experiment refutes your claim.

Comment: I also have a proof sketch: assuming the algorithm makes a uniform shuffle for array of size (n-1), we can extend it to size n by observing that the probability distribution of the first number chosen is correct and the rest of the algorithm is a shuffle of size (n-1). The base case of shuffling the empty list is trivial.

Comment: Maybe frame the proof as: How many trials do I need to get **either** 50 of the first number or 50 of the second number?  We'd find that **at most** this would take 99 trials (the case where you get up to 49/49 and then pull the tie-breaker).  So to get the equal 50/50, we'd pad one of the other number to match.  In every other case, one side would get to 50 before the 99th trial, which would cause more padding of the other number to get to 100 trials.

Comment: @SeKa, um, so? I'm not sure what exactly you are you trying to prove. If that's the lechlukasz' hypothesis, then it's false so no need to struggle.

Comment: Remember that a sequence containing 50 zeroes and 49 ones is more likely to end with zero so that may be a counter-argument to yours. Difficult to tell though.

Comment: @Rotsor Sorry when I read my comment again it does seem a bit out-of-place.  I was thinking about comparing the true random generator against one that forces the perfect 50/50 distribution.  I understand that yours uses what results to a "correcting" probability, but it feels like you would run into cases where you hit P(0) or P(1) before the end, or if not that extreme close to it.

Comment: To clarify: The algorithm above is no more likely to group identical numbers at the end than any "shuffle-type" process.  My rant(s) above were more about applying the "forcing" effect to random numbers in general, and not specifically about any shortfalls in this particular algorithm.  I apologize for any confusion this may have caused.

Comment: @SeKa, OK, I understand. However, I disagree on calling a particular random distribution "the true" one. Each distribution has its own place.

Comment: @Rotsor Agree that each distribution has value in its own right.  In this context I was using "true" as in "fair 50/50 probability" and not as in "the only correct".  Again, apologize for the unclear word choice :P

Answer (score 0):

You have already successfully created a random generator that returns `1` or `2` with equal probability.

As (many) other's have mentioned, your next request, to force an **exact** 50/50 distributions in 100 trials, does not fall in line with random number generation.  As shown in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/probability-of-getting-50-heads-from-tossing-a-coin-100-times, the realistic expectation of that occurring is only around 8%.  So even while you might *expect* 50 of each, that *exact* outcome is actually rather rare.

The Law of Large Numbers states that you should close in on expected value as your number of trials increases.

So for your actual question: How can I make the generator make an equal number for 1 and 2 in this case?

The best (humorous) answer I can come up with is: "Run it in an infinite loop."